# Concatenate two Response

Tags: java, xml-parsing, response

I have these two Reponse from `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`:

```
Response res1 = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                        .entity(new GenericEntity<ApplicationType>(val1) {
                        }).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).build();

Response res2 = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(new GenericEntity<ApplicationType>(val2) {
                }).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).build();
```

These two Response are in the same method that return `one Response`.
So, How can I concatenate these two Response to return it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a list as below or create another object to hold two `GenericEntity`s.

```
    List<GenericEntity<ApplicationType>> responseList = Arrays.asList(
            new GenericEntity<ApplicationType>(val1), 
            new GenericEntity<ApplicationType>(val2)
        );

    Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                               .entity(responseList)
                               .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                               .build();
```